# GridGain nodes from IDE execution doesnt communicate with local or remote ones

Tags: gridgain

I ran GridGain nodes in IDE (ex. Netbeans) from simple program, and all nodes that start from program in netbeans see each other;  all nodes that run from cmd.exe localy or on remote hosts see each other but nodes that runs from IDE dont see ones run locally or remote;

all tries was with default-config.xml out of the box;
also I tried with explicitly setted DiscoverySpi

My case is to have remote nodes and communicate with them from program while programming

Answer (score 1):

Default configuration uses multicast to discover the nodes. So you have to make sure that multicast is enabled and is properly working in your network.

Another way is to configure `TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder` and explicitly provide the list of IP addresses which node should try to connect when it joins the topology. If you have many boxes in your cluster, you don't have to provide all available addresses - 2-3 is usually enough, you just need to make sure that nodes on there boxes are started first.

Here is the configuration example:

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="ipFinder">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                <property name="addresses">
                    <list>
                        <value>192.168.0.1:47500</value>
                        <value>192.168.0.2:47500</value>
                        <value>192.168.0.3:47500</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: I tried discovery spi settings and all nodes from local/remote network see each other and communicate but they don't communicate with nodes started from code in IDE like NetBeans.

Comment: IDE is running on the same computer or in the same network in witch other nodes see each other

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you make sure that the version of the nodes started in NBeans is absolutely identical to the ones started from the command line?
2. If the above is Yes, then try setting IgniteConfiguration.setLocalHost() property to the interface you wish to bind to.